# enforcing a link into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

While I'm learning about iframe i found some of the URLs cannot be loaded into iframe. While i tried to load them they replace the current page with that iframe URL page. My friend suggested me to use an `iframe enforcer` but he is not sure about it. 
What I'm wondering is, if it is possible to enforce every url into iframe. If yes which is the best way to do so. Also if this is possible to block our site to load on any iframe. I'm so eager to learn about this.

One of the URL that is not loading is www.dinamalar.com

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you cannot load a website into a frame if it doesn't cooperate. Even if JavaScript is off, most browsers already support the [X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header). This is actually a security feature because a malicious website could load a trusted website into a frame and trick the user into clicking a link in it to start some action ([Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)).

That said, I think that MSIE's [`security="restricted"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute prevents frames from breaking out using JavaScript code the way dinamalar.com does it. I don't think that any browser other than MSIE implements this however (and they don't plan to either).